# Remove all Bootstrap 4 styling from .card-header

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am struggling to remove all Bootstrap 4 native styling from the Bootstrap `.card` component. There is a chance that it is actually not related to Bootstrap, however I do see it in Edge as well.

**Please help me remove this blue line displayed on a *selected* `.card-header`!**

[image]

I have tried various overrides like below:

```
.card-header {
    background-color: white;
    border-color: orange;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: this is outline, just add outline: none !important; and its done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing here is accessibility styling that bootstrap has added to help users see where there are currently focused on the user interface. The collapse component your using also uses the card component as well.

Although I don't recommend it, you can remove the accessibility styling no different than removing other styling like you showed above, however you need to access the `pseudo` class.

This accessibility styling is done through the pseudo element `focus`.

You can access the pseudo properties of a class by adding `:focus` at the end. In this cases the styling is done on a class called `.btn`. To change only buttons within an collapsible elements do the following.

```
.card .btn:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! And thank you for the explanation. Will help a lot going forward :D